# Is it possible to host a website in one server and host emails with this domain on another server?

Tags: email, smtp, web-hosting, domain-name

I have 2 servers, one with hostgator and a second one which is much faster. I would like to use the server on Hostgator for Email and the other one (which is faster) for the website.

For what I've tried it seems is not possible. While the domain is directed to the second server, If I use the hostgator's one for email accounts I can send emails but can't receive them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `A` DNS record to select host for WWW and `MX` DNS record to select host to receive emails for the domain.

**Warning 1**: Many mail servers auto-configure themselves with list of local email domains.
Fixing configuration of MTA server at web server host may be required.

**Warning 2:** Avoid using `CNAME` (alias) DNS records.  Mail/SMTP servers convert name with CNAME record to aliased name.

Comment: This helps me!! I don´t have points but thanks and have a good one!!!

Comment: Which MMTA/SMTP server do you use?

Comment: I'll use IMAP probably.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you're looking for is: mx-record.

Comment: Because ..? Can you expand?